# Need bulk Voice Mail vendor with API for application

Tags: untagged

My group is currently tasked with building a dynamic voicemail system for an online application.

We need to be able to create a new voicemail account for each new user who joins (ex: they get an account # w/pin and all use the same toll-free # for access), and do it programmatically (via API/webservice.) I'm looking for a low-to-mid cost vendor who has this type of functionality available.

Also, does anyone have any experience using this type of service (tips/gotchas)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain ASTERISK can do this without a problem.

Comment: I agree - Asterisk's is great for this.  FreePBX is also good